# rfcv take long time from the randomForest package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the rfcv function to do a random forest feature selection using raster data. I tried doing it as above with the following:

```
dfAll_train.cv <- replicate(2, rfcv(dfAll_train[-ncol(dfAll_train)], dfAll_train$CLASS_ID, cv.fold = 3, step = 1.5), simplify = FALSE)
```

However, it takes a long time (probably more than a day) to run the results. Therefore, I wonder if there is any way to save time.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!